# Cómo ordenar un arreglo en C# de la siguiente manera

Tags: c#, consola

mi profesor me pide este arreglo, pero no tengo la menor idea de cómo ordenarlo de esa forma. Se ordenarlo de mayor a menor, y viceversa, pero así como sería?
Datos ingresados:
4,7,1,9,0,5
Datos de salida:
5,0,9,1,7,4
Es en consola c#

Comment: Lo que está haciendo es imprimirlo del revés. Lo que tienes que hacer es recorrerlo desde la última posición hasta la primera (incluida).

Comment: Lo que pide tu profesor es que devuelvas los datos ingresados en orden inverso. La forma de hacerlo depende de como tengas implementada la captura de datos y de en que estructura estás almacenandolo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es recorrerlo al revés. Para ello utiliza un bucle inicializado a la última posición (array.Length-1) y que en cada paso disminuya la posición.

```
int[] array= new int[] { 4,7,1,9,0,5 };
for(int i=array.Length-1;i<0;i--)
{
    Console.write(array[i]);
}
```

Comment: Es de agradecer tu aportación, pero obviamente el OP nos viene con una tarea escolar, y si se la das hecha no va a aprender. Otra cosa es que mostrara su código si se encontrara con alguna dificultad en concreto, pero en estos casos está bien dar una indicación de como hacerlo. Dar la solución completa es contraproducente para su aprendizaje.

Comment: Gracias! Y tienes toda la razón en lo que mencionas. Me pasaba mucho antes con otras cosas pero a día de hoy no solo copio y pego, analizó lo que los demás me dicen. Tenía la idea más no la podía entablar. Conozco la ordenación y los métodos de lo mismo en arreglos, pero con esto si me enrede y el examen es hoy, trato de estudiar todo lo que puedo!  Saludos desde Culiacán, Sinaloa, México!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el

[Array.Reverse](https://www.dotnetperls.com/array-reverse)

algo como ser

```
int[] array= new int[] { 4,7,1,9,0,5 };

Array.Reverse(array);

foreach(int item in array){
   Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```